# How to make a sample 1D textures in modern opengl?

Tags: c, opengl, opengl-es, glsl

I created this simple program. It creates two textures, a 2D and a 1D texture binds them, etc.

*I can sample and draw from the 2D texture in my shader program with no problems. Trying to sample and draw from the 1D texture, the quad turns out black.*

If I don't use the 1D texture sample in the fragment shader below in the if..else.. statement, everything renders in black and white. Trying to use the sample, it only renders a black screen.

***If I do some hackery like this:***

```
if (i == maxIterations)
    {
       tcolor = vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    }
    else if(i <= 10)
    {
        tcolor = vec4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    } else if ( i >= 11)
    {
        tcolor = vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    }
```

***it also works..... How do I sample 1D textures?***

**source code below**

```
    glGenTextures(1, &colorTextureID);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, colorTextureID);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);


    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, Mode, colorSurface->w, colorSurface->h, 0, Mode, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, colorSurface->pixels);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    free(colorSurface);

    //mandi 1d texture
    glGenTextures(1, &mandiTextureID);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, mandiTextureID);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);


    glTexImage1D(GL_TEXTURE_1D, 0, Mode1, mandiSurface->w, 0, Mode1, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, mandiSurface->pixels);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, 0);
    free(mandiSurface);

    //render
    void render()
{
    glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    //glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
    glUseProgram(sp);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, colorTextureID);//ourTexture
    ourTexture = getUniformLocation(sp, "ourTexture");
    glUniform1i(ourTexture, 0);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, mandiTextureID);//mandiTexture
    mandiTexture = getUniformLocation(sp, "mandiTexture");
    glUniform1i(mandiTexture, 1);


    glBindVertexArray(verticesBuffer);
    viewMat = getUniformLocation(sp, "viewMat");
    modelMat = getUniformLocation(sp, "modelMat");
    projMat = getUniformLocation(sp, "projMat");

    maxIterLoc = getUniformLocation(sp, "maxIterations");
    centerLoc = getUniformLocation(sp, "center");
    scaleLoc = getUniformLocation(sp, "scale");

    glUniformMatrix4fv(viewMat, 1, GL_FALSE, vm.m);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(projMat, 1, GL_FALSE, opm.m);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(modelMat, 1, GL_FALSE, tm.m);

    glUniform1i(maxIterLoc, 20);
    glUniform1f(scaleLoc, scale);
    glUniform2f(centerLoc, cx, cy);

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

**Vertex shader**

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 icolor;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 vTexCoord;

uniform mat4 modelMat;
uniform mat4 viewMat;
uniform mat4 projMat;

out vec4 fcolor;
out vec2 fTexCoord;
out vec2 fCoord;

void main()
{
    gl_Position =  projMat * viewMat * modelMat * vec4(position, 1.0);

    fCoord = vec2(position);
    fTexCoord = vTexCoord;
    fcolor = vec4(icolor, 1.0f);
}
```

**Fragment shader**

```
#version 330 core

in vec4 fcolor;
in vec2 fTexCoord;
in vec2 fCoord;

uniform int maxIterations;
uniform vec2 center;
uniform float scale;

uniform sampler2D ourTexture;
uniform sampler1D mandiTexture;

out vec4 color;

void main()
{
   vec2 c, z;

    c.x = 1.3333 * (fCoord.x - 0.5) - center.x;
    c.y = (fCoord.y - 0.5) - center.y;

        int i;
        z = c;
        for(i=0; i<maxIterations; i++) {
            float x = (z.x * z.x - z.y * z.y) + c.x;
            float y = (z.y * z.x + z.x * z.y) + c.y;

            if((x * x + y * y) > 4.0) break;
            z.x = x;
            z.y = y;
        }

    vec4 tcolor;

    if (i == maxIterations)
    {
       tcolor = vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    }
    else
    {
       /* tcolor = vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);  this works but only renders black and white */
       tcolor = texture(mandiTexture, float(i)).rgba; /* only renders black screen */
    }

    /* color = texture(ourTexture, fTexCoord) * fcolor; //this also works */
    color = tcolor;
}
```

Comment: texture coordinates are in the range [0,1]

Comment: @Olaf vertex and fragment shaders.

Comment: That does not answer my question.

Comment: @dari this was the answer but to a new graphics programmer it can be really cryptic.

Comment: @Olaf: There are two different languages here: C and GLSL. The only code that has a main function in this question is in GLSL. `void main (void)` is valid in GLSL and much of its syntax looks identical to C, so you might easily confuse the two.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: Thanks for the explanation, I got it. Yes, that irritated me. So I assume the second snippet is the (mal-formated) C code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you are using a texture co-ordinate in the range of 0 to `maxIterations` (the possible values of `i`) to look up the value in your 1D texture. As mentioned by dari in a comment, the texture coordinates are in the range of 0-1, ignoring wrapping and clamping.

So, divide `i` by `maxIterations` to get a coordinate in the 0-1 range:

```
tcolor = texture(mandiTexture, float(i) / float(maxIterations)).rgba;
```